# Problem with dividing variables together, returns an error about operand types and 'str'

Tags: python

I'm coding a basic BMI calculator for some small practice, but I can't seem to divide the variables of weight and height by each other.

I've tried changing them from int to str, but I couldn't figure out how.

```
h = input("Enter your height in cm: ")

print(h)

w = input("Enter your weight in kg: ")

print(w)

print(w/h)
```

the final line is the issue, everything else is fine

I expect the output to come out as the BMI, with the variables dividing, i.e w = 9 and h = 3, I'd expect 3.

Answer (score 1):

The input method accepts input as string.For dividing you need to convert those input to int.The below code will work.

```
h = int(input("Enter your height in cm: "))

print(h)

w = int(input("Enter your weight in kg: "))

print(w)

print(w/h)
```